# Cloudflare Setup with Azure WebApp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, cloudflare

I have a domain name registered with GoDaddy, e.g., "mysite.com", and have followed the Azure [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) to map that domain's CNAME and A records to my Azure WebApp, i.e.,

[image]

I then updated GoDaddy's nameservers to point to cloudflare so cloudflare is now in charge of my DNS records, i.e.,

[image]

Within cloudflare I have SSL set to Full and the certificate appears to be active

[image]

and my DNS records in cloudflare pointing to my azurewebsites domain name, i.e.,

[image]

It has been over 36 hours since I updated the nameservers, but as you can see from cloudflares DNS records screenshot above (see Status), all traffic appears to be routing around cloudflare directly to Azure, i.e., I'm not hitting cloudflare. Putting domain mysite.azurewebsites.net in [whatsmydns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) also shows everything pointing to Azure.

What have I missed in the setup to ensure all traffic routes through cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late but you need to click on that grey cloud icon in Cloudflares settings. The icon will then go orange and the traffic will be routed through Cloudflare.

Comment: But he asked "What have I missed in the setup to ensure all traffic routes through cloudflare?". I answered this by pointing out that he has to click on the grey icon in his Cloudflare Dashboard to route the traffic through Cloudflare. Correct me if I am wrong but thats an anwser, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare appears to transparently replace all CNAME records to A, so this CNAME record is not visible for Azure. You have to change nameservers of your domain to its original ones (provided by GoDaddy in your case), add CNAME through GoDaddy DNS panel, wait for Azure to see it, approve domain in Azure, and only then migrate to CloudFlare.

Comment: You can add CNAME records and bind it in Azure if you disable the proxy (orange cloud), add the custom domain on the webapp and then add back the orange cloud)